# @aws/dynamodb-data-mapper: How to write ConditionExpression in QueryOptions filter area?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I would like to fetch data from DynamoDB database by using [AWS-DynamoDB-Data-Mapper][1]. I am using QueryIterator and to provide indexName, limit, filter purpose, I am using [QueryOptions][2]. In QueryOptions, I would like to use **filter?: ConditionExpression**. Where I would like to use **contains()** function, but I am not able to form ConditionExpression in the below example -

{
"Id": {"N": "456" },
"ProductCategory": {"S": "Sporting Goods" },
"Price": {"N": "650" }
}

```
const paginator = dbMapper.query(
  Products,
  {
    Id: 456,
    Price: between(500, 1000)
  },
  { 
    indexName: 'indexByPriceId', 
    limit: 10, 
    scanIndexForward: false,
    filter: contains(ProductCategory, 'goods')
   } 
);
```

It returns an syntax error in this line `filter: contains(ProductCategory, 'goods')`, it says ContainsPredicate is not a ConditionExpression.

Please help me out by providing me the ConditionExpression in QueryOptions.
[1]: https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-data-mapper-js
[2]: https://awslabs.github.io/dynamodb-data-mapper-js/packages/dynamodb-data-mapper/interfaces/queryoptions.html#projection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very late response, but if anyone else is looking for how to use this, the best documentation I was able to find is here: https://awslabs.github.io/dynamodb-data-mapper-js/packages/dynamodb-expressions

In order to use *contains*, you need to pass an object of type *[SimpleConditionExpression](https://awslabs.github.io/dynamodb-data-mapper-js/packages/dynamodb-expressions/globals.html#simpleconditionexpression)* to *filter* like so:

```
filter: { subject: 'DB_COLUMN', ...contains('STRING_TO_SEARCH') }
```

So for the example above it should be:

```
const paginator = dbMapper.query(
  Products,
  {
    Id: 456,
    Price: between(500, 1000)
  },
  { 
    indexName: 'indexByPriceId', 
    limit: 10, 
    scanIndexForward: false,
    filter: { subject: 'ProductCategory', ...contains('goods') }
   } 
);
```